# Floating point: how many matching significant figures?

Tags: c, floating-point

In C, Given two single or double precision floating point numbers, is there an easy way to determine how many of their significant figures "match"? I.e. if I have two such numbers with decimal representation `1.64298272` and `1.64298296` I would like to obtain the result `7`. If I was concerned with decimal places this would be easy but I'm not sure how to go about it if I'm interested in significant figures.

Comment: Stringify them, then walk through the string comparing each character.

Comment: Premise is invalid.  `float` and `double` can represent _exactly_ many values, but not `1.64298272` and `1.64298296`.  So do you want to compare _exact_ or _rounded_ values ? And if rounded, how far to _round_?

Comment: Are you sure it is **not** about decimal places? `1.2345` and `12.345` have the same significant digits. Otherwise you could take `log10` of their `fabs`olute difference to get at (or near) the divergent digit.

Comment: @ryyker: while that is possible it does not seem very efficient.

Comment: @chux: You're right, I should have chosen a better example, I'm interested in the _exact_ case.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Significant digits assuming same decimal point position.

Comment: It has to be said: Distinguishing decimal digits like this is not what binary floating-point was designed for, and, when somebody is trying to do it, it is generally an indication they are on the wrong track for their goal. Why are you trying to do this, and what is your actual goal?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: My goal is exactly this, I have two large sequences of floating point numbers and I would like to obtain statistics about the decimal significant figures up to which their elements match. The "use case" is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, the use case is relevant. Floating-point arithmetic is largely designed to approximate real-number arithmetic and generally works well with continuous functions. The data it is designed for—physical measurements, mathematical explorations of real numbers, and such—are not “decimal.” Measurements of physical objects are messy; they do not chunk into decimal slots. If we measured the mass of a bunch of objects together and then measured them separately and added them, we would expect some error, but that error would be better measured as a relative figure (error divided by total)…

Comment: … than by the number of digits that happened to match when the numbers are converted to decimal. E.g., 3.9999 and 4.0001 are much closer together than 4.3301 and 4.3398 even though the former have 0 digits in common and the latter have 3.

Comment: Indeed, I think OP's "matching significant figures" is really just asking for something like the log of the relative error.  There isn't anything inherently decimal about that, except for the arbitrary choice of logs base 10.

Comment: Peter, if the values were 2.0 and 1.999999999999999, would you want a result of 0?

Comment: @chux: Yes. I know this is a sort of wonky question in that regard but I know what I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do an *exact* compare, the value must be converted with sufficient precision.  `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` (typical 17) is enough for `double` to make unique strings as suggested by [@ryyker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325186/floating-point-how-many-matching-significant-figures/62325622#comment110228183_62325186)

Form a string for both values

```
//         -   d   .    digits - 1        e   -  expo \0
#define N (1 + 1 + 1  + DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 1 + 1 + 5 + 1)
char buf[N + 10];  // Some extra too to cope with strange NaN payloads
// Consider changing round mode to "round towards 0.0.  See below notes.
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf,"%+.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, value);
```

After testing for same sign and exponent, walk leading digits.

Some sample hacked code.

```
if (buf1[0] != buf2[0]) return 0; // sign test
e1 = strchr(buf1, 'e');
e2 = strchr(buf1, 'e');
if (strcmp(e1,e2)) return 0; // expo test (non-finite concerns omitted here for brevity)
digit = 0;
s1 = buf1;
s2 = buf2;
while (s1 < e1 && s2 < e2) {
  if (isdigit(*s1)) {
    if (*s1 == *s1) digit++;
    else break;
  }
  s1++; s2++;
}
return digit;
```

---

If code attempts to do this without `s*printf()`, the math involved to examine a binary based floating-point number and convert to decimal for compare will effectively re-do what `sprintf()` does already.

---

Limitations:

This answers is at best a start.  Consider `foo(0.0, 0.0)` and `foo(DBL_TRUE_MIN, DBL_TRUE_MIN)` here would return `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`.  As `DBL_TRUE_MIN` is *about* 4.940656...e-324 yet as an exact decimal has about 751 significant digits, should 751 be returned?

Research is needed also to consider [edge cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325186/floating-point-how-many-matching-significant-figures/62325622?noredirect=1#comment110229170_62325622).

See [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325186/floating-point-how-many-matching-significant-figures/62325622?noredirect=1#comment110231825_62325622) good idea about first changing the rounding mode.  IAC, using `sprintf()` is limited by a quality of implementation.

---

[Update]

If a C library implements FP per [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Character_representation), then to well handle many cases, a +3 to the precision is recommended.

```
char buf[N + 3 + 10];
// Consider changing round mode to "round towards 0.0.  See below notes.
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf,"%+.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 3 - 1, value);
```

Comment: Could this process be defined as using strigification and walking the buffer? :)  +1

Comment: One potential caveat: Some `double` value might be x.xxx…xxx999…xxx5exxx, and formatting it to `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` might produce “x.xxx…xxy000exxx”, where that y is one more than the x that was there, and that might produce a false positive (or negative) match in some digits with another value in which the formatted digits matched (or did not) when the full digits do not (or do). I would have to think about it further to be sure the possibility exists.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True that deeper thought is deserved to validate..  IAC, the conversion from `double` to string is subject to the quality of `sprintf()` which may come into play.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose this works. Is there no way to achieve this without stringification though?

Comment: @Peter As answered above, yes code can do  this without stringification, yet code would simply repeat `sprintf()` code.  See [print a double - exactly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485).

Comment: @chux: Alright, that makes sense to me, I will go with this and try to imitate formatted printing if I require even more performance.

Comment: @Peter Concerning "imitate formatted printing if I require even more performance": converting a `double` to decimal digits is very easy to inject inexactness in the process.  I recommend to first try going for correct functionality before attempting speed-up.  Further, Perhaps post your code on Code Review after you get it going?

Comment: For .109 in IEEE-754 binary64 round-to-nearest, the `double` value is 1.0899999999999999966693309261245303787291049957275390625e-01, but formatting with `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` (or `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG-1`) digits produces “1.09000000000000000e-01”, so this produces incorrect results—it will say it has three digits in common with .109375 when it only has two.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes.  I too am finding corner cases that fail.  Printing with more than `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` digits will reduce the likelihood, if `sprintf()` is of sufficient quality.  Now the question becomes 1) what is the precision needed for all pairs of `double` (its less than 800) and 2) if `sprintf()` cannot be relied on performing to that (likely it may not), than how to do so otherwise?  I'll ponder some more too.

Comment: Rounding toward zero with `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` significant digits would suffice, but I do not know if/which `snprintf` implementations honor a change of the floating-point rounding mode. Seems like Apple Clang 11 on macOS 10.14.6 does.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for that insight.  I agree the round-to-0 avoids the pesky 99999 overflow [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325186/floating-point-how-many-matching-significant-figures/62325622?noredirect=1#comment110231379_62325622).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I expect `sprintf()` to employ the round mode, yet there is  variation in implementations.  If the library adheres to IEEE 754 requires only [17 + 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Character_representation) digit conversion correctness.  Beyond that, looks like we would need to craft our own code.  (oops - that is decimal to binary limit).  Well time to get out of the [rabbit hole](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/rabbit-hole/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer for the question. I was searching for a solution to the same problem on SO, but all solutions that I found involve conversion of the numbers to string.

Finally, I was able to solve the problem in a pure mathematical way:

```
// compute number of most significant digits that agree of two numbers.
// for example, MatchingSigFigs(1.64298272, 1.64298296) => 7

int matchingSigFigs(double a, double b)
{
    return (a == b) ? 17 : (int) (floor(log10(fmax(fabs(a), fabs(b)))) -
                                  floor(log10(fabs(a - b))));
}
```